# Pressure loss in pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, friction, flow

I am trying to solve for Reynolds number in a problem. However, I do not have the velocity of the water which flows through the pipe. Am I supposed to make up a number for the flow speed of the liquid inside the pipe or is this a mistake in the problem itself?

The pipe dimensions are given to me (its diameter, vertical and horizontal length), I have acquired the K-values ($\zeta$) for the 90° elbow, the inlet, and the outlet of the pipe and for both the gate valves in which the liquid flows through.

To make it easier, the velocity at point 1 is negligible, as small as $c_1 ≈ 0 \frac ms $, $c_1$ being the velocity at the point which is on the free surface (which is on a water tank). Still, I do not know how to get the flow speed of the liquid.

I managed to get the relative pipe roughness, as well, but it's not very handy as I don't have the Reynolds number which is required of me to solve my problem.

If you are wondering, I need the Reynolds number so I can get my friction number and to solve the pressure drop between the two points of 1 & 2, and also the velocity of point 2 which is on the exit of the pipe.

I can provide with image of the system if interested.

Comment: You pretty much know the overall pressure difference and you need to determine the mass flow rate that makes good on this pressure difference.  So this is a trial and error calculation.  Assume a mass flow rate and see if it matches the overall pressure difference.  If it doesn't match, adjust the mass flow rate, and try again.

Comment: Not exactly.  In place of the delta p, you need the dissipation term.

Comment: As Chet wrote. Make an assumption, e.g. laminar flow, then calculate flow rate and calculate $\text{Re}$. If this indicates laminar flow you're done. If not, assume turbulent flow and calculate flow velocity and $\text{Re}$. It's a classic problem, very common in Real World.

Comment: Is an assumption of the velocity of the water in the pipe of $ c_{avg} = 3 \frac ms $ good? I think this will be turbulent, by the way.

Comment: I appreciate it Chet, however I am not familiar of the dissipation term, at least not in the English language. I deleted this comment earlier, this is what I am going to use, but you said I needed the dissipation term:

$p_1 + \rho gh_1 + c_1^2 \frac \rho 2 = p_2 + \rho gh_2 + c_2^2 \frac \rho 2 + {\Delta}p_{12} $ 

where ${\Delta}p_{12}$ is the pressure difference between point 1 and 2.

$(\lambda \frac ld + \zeta_{inlet} + \zeta_{valve_1} + \zeta_{elbow} + \zeta_{valve_2} + \zeta_{outlet}) c_l^2 \frac \rho 2 $

Comment: It is basically the frictional pressure drop in the pipe and connections.

Comment: @ChetMiller Oh, so it's the equation of $\Delta p_{12}$, right? I mean to type that it's the pressure loss between the two points, not the pressure difference.

Comment: It is only the frictional pressure difference, not the part related to change in gravitational potential energy or kinetic energy.

Comment: I still do not understand, doctor. I am rereading your comments, but everything is still unclear. Could you explain it for me, once again? @ChetMiller

Comment: See Transport Phenomena, Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, Chapter 7, Sections 7.4 and 7.5.

Comment: @ChetMiller, Thanks for the recommendation. I think I'm close. I managed to get the following equation

$\rho g h_1 = \frac {c_{2}{^{2}} }2 \rho + \underbrace{(\lambda \frac{l}d + \zeta_{in}+\zeta_{v1}+\zeta{_{bend}}+\zeta_{v2})\frac {c_{2}{^{2}} }2 \rho}_{\Delta{p_{loss_{12}}}}$

and since dimensions don't change the velocity inside the pipe is the same as the velocity at the second point (which is at the end point of the pipe). I still don't know how I would calculate both Reynolds number AND the velocity at the second point. Second velocity, Reynolds number and lambda are not known.

Comment: Isn't $\rho v A$ constant?

Comment: I am not sure; I don't need the mass flow rate.